# What could be blocking my DynDNS?

Tags: dynamic-dns

I made an account on DynDNS and with my new router (Zyxel) I can't seem to connect to it. I want to be able to connect to my router when I am somewhere else in the world – just like I can connect to its IP address and access its information. I know this is possible.

The following is happening: When I am on my home network connected via wireless and I type in the link (`example.dyndns.org`) I get to the page and I can log in fine. NO problem at all.

When I am somewhere else, or on my phone, and type in the same site it doesn't work. Something seems to be blocking my DynDNS from outside – but from the inside it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Most routers restrict external IP's from accessing the control settings.  This prevents unauthorized users (the rest of the internet) from forwarding ports and doing other mischievous things.

On my [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) firmware router, I have the ability to override this by allowing WAN (Wide-Area Network) requests to adjust my router settings.  I highly recommend you do *NOT* allow this.

Another option would be to to create an ssh tunnel to a computer inside of your network.  This would create a secure way for you to create a 'VPN' of some sort.  Once you set up your browser to use your ssh tunnel correctly, you can then access your router's web interface as if you were accessing it locally from the machine you tunnel into.

Comment: What is the point in resticting external ip's and dyndns ability on a router then? If they put the function in there and still block everything?

Comment: The problem here is that he is trying to access his *ROUTER* and not a machine within the router's LAN.  If he were trying to access a machine within the LAN, he would need to use port forwarding.  In this case, however, it seems to be that he is trying to do something fundamentally insecure with his router.  Routers have special security measures built in to prevent this type of activity by default (which is very smart).  If you want to open your router to the internet as long as the router has that capability, you can.  A better solution would be to create a ssh tunnel and access 'locally'.

Answer (score 0):

The router is probably dropping traffic from the outside. You probably need to set up port forwarding from routers address (which is in dyndns) to your desktop machine for port 80 (port 80 = web browsing)

if you do "ping you.dyndsn.com" the IP it shows you should be your network's the external IP. The one that is owned by your modem. If you go to http://www.whatsmyip.us/ it will show you what dyndns should be set to.

Then, you should then setup port forwarding in your routers config to forward web traffic (port 80) from the router to whatever web server you have.

If you read this guide: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/ZyXEL/Prestige600/BitTorrent.htm you need to go to the page in the configuration site that says "Start port, End Port and IP Address" and it needs to read "80,80 and the IP of the machine which is running the web server".

Comment: okay, what if i don't want to connect to a my desktop machine. but just the router itself? Don't I connect to a computer this way? 
Also in my router it asks for default server address, is that the router or my whastmyip.us one? thx

Comment: You will still need to open port 80 from the outside to receive traffic. Aslong as it's supported then please use a non-standard port for security... Leaving port 80 wide open will attract alot of 'attention'. :)

Comment: alright I understand. What if I just want to connect to my home network and not just the router. So I could see everyone who is on there? I'm not trying to expose myself to the world :P